# WPF XAML: Why SelectedItem is not working on ListBox when I click ComboBox in it?

Tags: combobox, listbox

Why SelectedItem is not working on ListBox when I click ComboBox in it, below the code:

```
   <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItemDataGrid}>
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
           <ComboBox />
           </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ListBox>
```

I need to get the SelectedItem in ListBox, when I click ComboBox.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ListBox I am using DataGrid.

```
     <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSourceDataGrid}"
                HeadersVisibility="None" 
                GridLinesVisibility="None"
                SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItemDataGrid}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSourceComboBox}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItemComboBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Thank you.